# How to manually space two images in a environment defined by a personal package

Tags: package-writing

I am trying to create a package in order to be able to write in Ithkuil (it's an artificial language). To do this, I need to have an environment `\begin{ithkuil} ... \end{ithkuil}` in which the characters to be added are distinguished, using the command `\ch{im1, im2}` where im1.png and im2.png are images overlapped with each other. In other words, each character is formed by the superposition of several images. With the following code, I managed to do it, but there is still a problem. I'm not very skilled at creating packages; I've just started to understand them a little bit. However, this is for a university assignment, and I have limited time. That's why I tried to seek help from ChatGPT, but it doesn't seem to understand my problem. The images created by the various `\ch{...}` commands are too far apart horizontally, and I would like to have a function to reduce this distance, for example `\begin{ithkuil}[4em][0.5em] ... \end{ithkuil}` to set the general dimension of the characters at 4em and the horizontal distances between the characters at 0.5em.

```
\ProvidesPackage{ithkuil}[2023/07/29 LaTeX package for Ithkuil]

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newlength{\ithkuil@imgwidth}

\newenvironment{ithkuil}[1][1em]{
  \setlength{\ithkuil@imgwidth}{#1}
  \def\ch##1{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]
      \foreach \imgname in {##1}{
        \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=base west] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\ithkuil@imgwidth]{\imgname}};
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\imgwidth}{\ithkuil@imgwidth+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}
        \path (0,0) node[minimum width=\imgwidth, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {};
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \par\noindent\ignorespaces
}{
  \par\ignorespacesafterend
}
```

Comment: you have spurious spaces everywhere. End of lines offen matter! Use % to suppress the space they create.